# PHP replacing string with link

Tags: php, regex

Okay so thanks to folks on this forum I finally got a simple twitter online website working. Now I have run into another problem.

I have a twitter feed say the sample text is:

> The cat will always be in the bag @folks @charliesheen

Now I had the idea of using regular expressions to find all @***_*** strings in the text and replace them with

```
<a href="index.php?".$(matched_string - @)>matched_string</a>
```

Any ideas on how I can possibly go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something I hacked up quickly.  `\S` means "any character that's not whitespace".

```
$str = 'The cat will always be in the bag @folks @charliesheen';
$str = preg_replace('/@(\S*)/', '<a href="index.php?$1">$1</a>', $str);
```

EDIT: To be safe, you should make sure all the characters in the URL are "url-safe".

```
$str = 'The cat will always be in the bag @folks @charliesheen';
$str = preg_replace_callback('/@(\S*)/', function($x){
    return '<a href="index.php?'.urlencode($x[1]).'">'.$x[1].'</a>';
}, $str);
```

Comment: Oh my god I love you! I was looking for that $1...couldn't find it anywhere. THANKS A LOT!

Comment: @hakre: I could also make sure the regex only matches url-safe characters too. :-P

Comment: @user1123599: Check the docs for [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). :-)

Comment: @Rocket: Sure, that's the other way round. But you should do one of those two and not none (as in your current answer). Otherwise I'd say it's technically wrong even, because OP asks for URL and not just some re-formatted string.

Comment: @hakre: Ok, I added a solution to `urlencode` using `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: @Rocket: That's fine! Always take care of the average joe here that just copies and pastes code from the site. So it's better to provide a little more safe code.

Comment: @hakre: True.  It's 3am, so I was being lazy.

Comment: I ended up changing the regex to '/@([A-Za-z0-9_]*)/' because for twitter handles characters such as ':' are not allowed...just in case someone is interested in the future...Thanks for the encoded url function...REALLY helpful!

Comment: @user1123599: That looks like a better regex.  It was 3am, so that was the best I had.